# Вопросы по installshield

Tags: windows, vlc, installshield, реестр, activex

Добрый день!

Есть пару вопросов по работе с этой замечательной программой)

Делаю инсталлятор плагина vlc для работы в браузерах, плагин состоит главным образом из двух дллок activex компонента и mozilla plugin. Но не получается корректно их зарегистрировать в реестре. Как это можно сделать средствами installshield при создании инсталлятора?

По идее, чтобы зарегистрировать dll с activex достаточно выполнить из консоли команду `regsvr32 путь\до\activex.dll`, можно ли как это сделать в момент инсталляции? Если даже в ручную копировать все ключи, то путь указанный в них будет действителен только для моей системы, в отличие от других операционок. И как быть в таком случае с 64х битной версией, там же наверняка все немного отличаться должно?

И второй вопрос, как можно при создании инсталлятора настроить автообновление?

Или может подскажете русскоязычные ресурсы по данной тематике?

Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос про registy еще актуален? В InstallShield-е можно напрямую указать что и как прописывать в реестре (например project assistant->application registry), но это может немного отличаться от версии к версии. Какую версию InstallShield Вы используете? В вашем случае один из вариантов решения такой:

1. Зарегистрировать activex.dll вручную из коммандной строки.
2. Посмотреть, что и как записалось в реестре.
3. В InstallShield-е создать аналогичные ключи и вписать аналогичные значения в application registry. Примерно так.

P.S. Русскоязычных ресурсов по InstallShield я не видел. символыкончились

Поискать что-то на русском по InstallShield можно на msdn, хотя честно я сомневаюсь, что там будет что-то существенное.

Да, что касается 64-битных систем. Лучше бы сделать аналогично: сначала вручную, а потом уже вписать нужные значения через InstallShield.

P.S.S. Мануалы на английском есть на сайте разработчика:
http://www.flexerasoftware.com
Но, честно говоря, сделаны они не очень. Зато в InstallShield в принципе управление сделано интуитивно понятно. Но это ИМХО.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ)
Для activex компонента в самой инсталлшилд указал что он должен быть сам зарегистрирован и все заработало, для остальных компонентов прописал в ручную. В 64х битной системе проблем пока что не возникает..
Но для меня так и остается открыт вопрос как настроить автообнолвение всей этой системы, вот с этим так и не разобрался(